# How to lag the same column in dplyr?

Tags: r, excel, dplyr

I am trying to mutate and lag the same column in R dplyr, per the reproducible code at the bottom of this post. That code doesn't give my what I'm looking for. What am I doing wrong?

Running the code gives me these incorrect results, where column `nameCntMult` is the one I'm trying to lag:

```
> dataFill
# A tibble: 6 x 4
  Name   Code nameCnt nameCntMult
  <chr> <dbl>   <int>       <dbl>
1 R         0       1           1
2 R         0       2           2
3 T         0       1           1
4 R         0       3           3
5 N         1       1          NA
6 N         1       2           2
```

When I'm looking for these results, rendered in XLS:

[image]

Reproducible code:

```
library(dplyr)

data <- 
  data.frame(
    Name = c("R","R","T","R","N","N"),
    Code = c(0,0,0,0,1,1)
  )

dataFill <-data %>%
  group_by(Name, Code) %>%
    mutate(nameCnt = row_number())%>%
    mutate(nameCntMult = nameCnt * 2) %>%
    mutate(nameCntMult = ifelse(Code == 0, nameCnt, lag(nameCntMult))) %>%
  ungroup()

dataFill
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing the order of `mutate`s and `ungroup` would get you the answer you're looking for:

```r
library(dplyr)

data <- 
  data.frame(
    Name = c("R","R","T","R","N","N"),
    Code = c(0,0,0,0,1,1)
  )

dataFill <-data %>%
  group_by(Name, Code) %>%
  mutate(nameCnt = row_number())%>%
  mutate(nameCntMult = nameCnt * 2) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(nameCntMult = ifelse(Code == 0, nameCntMult, lag(nameCntMult))) %>%
  mutate(nameCntMult = ifelse(Code == 0, nameCntMult, lag(nameCntMult)))

dataFill
#> # A tibble: 6 × 4
#>   Name   Code nameCnt nameCntMult
#>   <chr> <dbl>   <int>       <dbl>
#> 1 R         0       1           2
#> 2 R         0       2           4
#> 3 T         0       1           2
#> 4 R         0       3           6
#> 5 N         1       1           6
#> 6 N         1       2           6
```

by also lagging the last 6 twice. When mutating before ungrouping the lag looks for the last value *in that group*, but cannot find it in your row 5 because it's the first of that group.

But this might not be the full answer you're looking for. Do you want `nameCntMult` to be the double of the last `nameCnt` value in a row where `Code == 0`?

## Edit - fuller solution using only `dplyr`

Here's a way to do it across as many rows as needed:

```r
data |> 
  group_by(Name, Code) |> 
  mutate(nameCnt = row_number()) |> 
  ungroup() |> 
  mutate(nameCntMult = ifelse(Code == 0, nameCnt * 2, NA)) |> 
  mutate(grp = cumsum(!is.na(nameCntMult))) |> 
  group_by(grp) |> 
  mutate(nameCntMult = max(nameCntMult, na.rm = TRUE)) |> 
  ungroup() |> 
  select(-grp)

#> # A tibble: 6 × 4
#>   Name   Code nameCnt nameCntMult
#>   <chr> <dbl>   <int>       <dbl>
#> 1 R         0       1           2
#> 2 R         0       2           4
#> 3 T         0       1           2
#> 4 R         0       3           6
#> 5 N         1       1           6
#> 6 N         1       2           6
```

(works by first assigning `NA`s to rows with `Code == 1`, then grouping these with previous non-NA value with a temporary `grp` variable and replacing the `max(nameCntMult)` across these rows)

Comment: If I add a new row to `data`, i.e. `add_row(data, Name = 'N', Code = 1)`, you need to  lag the last 6 three times, right?

Comment: yes that would be the drawback of this way of working. there should be a tidier way, will post update shortly

Comment: Hi Andy, your post correctly calculates the different test scenarios I ran. Very simply put, `nameCntMult` should be the value of the immediately prior row if the current row Code > 0. If current row Code = 0 then nameCntMult is current row nameCnt * 2. I look forward to your update!

Comment: I'm trying to keep this is dplyr (or Base R) in order to avoid "package bloat"!

Comment: I like the `purrr` solution posted here as well, but have made a slightly more-lined solution using only `dplyr` and posted as edit above.

Answer (score 3):

This is a ***recursive*** computation dependent on 2 vectors, i.e. `nameCnt` and `Code`. In this case you could use `accumulate2()` from `purrr`.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

fun <- function(x, y, code) if(code == 0) y * 2 else x

data %>%
  group_by(Name, Code) %>%
  mutate(nameCnt = row_number()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(nameCntMult = accumulate2(nameCnt, Code, fun, .init = NA)[-1] %>% flatten_dbl)

# # A tibble: 6 × 4
#   Name   Code nameCnt nameCntMult
#   <chr> <dbl>   <int>       <dbl>
# 1 R         0       1           2
# 2 R         0       2           4
# 3 T         0       1           2
# 4 R         0       3           6
# 5 N         1       1           6
# 6 N         1       2           6
```

---

There is also a `base` equivalent of `accumulate2`, i.e. `Reduce()`.

```r
... %>%
  mutate(nameCntMult = Reduce(function(x, y) if(Code[y] == 0) nameCnt[y] * 2 else x,
                              1:n(), init = NA, accumulate = TRUE)[-1])
```

Comment: very nice, I do love the tidyness of `purrr`!